# How do i save stream socket connections and resuse them in Windows store apps?

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, stream-socket-client

My app lets users connect to each other to share messages and such using streamsockets.

The app has a streamSocket Listener that, when the `onConnectionReceived` is called, it returns the socket that is connecting and sending  a request to the app.

The app will have MANY sockets connecting to it, each socket will be carrying different requests the app must carry out.

My questions are:

1. What is the best practice for saving these Socket connections so i can reuse them later and write to them?
2. How can  i have my app handle each connections request seperatly and at the same time? Meaning, i dont want my app writing a response to the wrong streamsocket that sent the request.